# 2001 Kawasaki zzr600

Tags: motorcycle, no-crank-no-start, kawasaki, spark

I got the bike it had a burnt wire and  didn't have a key so I put a resistor on the gray wire issue too so it would be 6 volts now I'm getting 12 volts to the coral but it still acts like it's not fire what should I do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Reading your question, I'm not really sure what you're talking about? I have no reference for a gray wire or why you'd do anything with it? Can you post a picture of what you're doing with maybe a better explanation as to why you are doing what you're doing. We'd really like to help you, but I'm having an issue understanding.